# failed to compute cache key: failed to create hash for <DIR>: operation not supported

Tags: macos, docker

while attempting to build an image in Docker/macOS, I get the following error:

> failed to compute cache key: failed to create hash for
> /app-temp/client/dist: operation not supported

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as ui-build
WORKDIR /app-temp
COPY client/ ./client/
RUN cd client && npm install
RUN cd client && npm run build


FROM node:lts-alpine as api-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=ui-build /app-temp/client/dist ./client/dist
COPY server/ ./server/
RUN cd server && npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "/app/server/src/index.js"]
```

And the docker command that I am using is:

```
docker build -t test-image .
```

Now, **note that the image is successfully built in a Linux machine**. However, the above-mentioned **error persists in a macOS machine**.

I am running macOS Big Sur 11.2.1.

Any ideas as to how solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm running BigSur 11.2.3 with the Docker Engine V20.10.5. I ran into this issue after updating my engine to the above version. You may want to try downgrading your Docker Engine version to see if the problem persists. This will help isolate the issue
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1939

Answer (score 5):

just in case someone else finds himself here

Look in your .dockerignore file if dist is in the list

Also, try building with BUILDKIT disabled

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in my case it looks like an issue with the Dockerfile being old and outdated referencing files that no longer exist in the expected location, as opposed to the build process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna throw my solution out there.

Setup: .net 5 web app with docker enabled, contains a dockerfile that was created by visual studio.

There was a step where the docker file was saying to copy my csproj up to the parent folder. I edited the source directory to from `parent/myproject.csproj` to `myproject.csproj` then I ran docker build and it worked.

Im assuming that when I run docker build I was down one level in the child folder where the dockerfile lives, and the paths just werent lining up.